# Angular Directive Bi-directional scope not updating template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've got an angular directive `esResize` and I'm having a problem using bi-directional binding on an isolate scope.

```
window.estimation.directive('esResize', function() {
    return {
        restrict:'C',
        scope: {
            pointGrid: '='
        },
        template: "<h2>{{ pointGrid }}</h2><ul><li ng-repeat='card in pointGrid track by $id(card)'>{{ card }}</li></ul>",
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.shiftTicket = function() {
                $scope.pointGrid.push("New Ticket");
            };
        },

        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var height;    
            element.resizable({ 
                grid: [ 10, 20 ],
                handles: "n, s",
                start: function(event, ui) {
                    //initialize method
                },
                resize: function(event, ui) {
                    scope.shiftTicket();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

When `resize` is triggered, `pointGrid` has "New Ticket" pushed to it when I output it to the console. However, the template does not update. Am I misunderstanding how bindings link to views or is there something else at play here?

Edit: pointGrid in the view is just an Array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `$scope.$apply();` after you update the scope value in the jquery plugin callback. This is because it was not triggered within angular's own cycles as it would with a ng-click or $http callback.

```
resize: function(event, ui) {
    scope.shiftTicket();
    scope.$apply(); // Should tell angular that this has updated
}
```

Comment: Spot on. Thank you. Will accept in 2 minutes when I'm allowed.

Comment: not sure if thats going to do it. You should change `pointGrid: '='` to `pointGrid: '&'`. Just dealt with this same issue and fixed it that way. Did  calling `scope.$apply` work?